# Basic BackgroundWorker usage with parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, backgroundworker

My process intensive method call that I want to perform in a background thread looks like this:

```
object.Method(paramObj, paramObj2);
```

All three of these objects are ones I have created. Now, from the initial examples I have seen, you can pass an object into a backgroundworker's DoWork method. But how should I go about doing this if I need to pass additional parameters to that object, like I'm doing here? I could wrap this in a single object and be done with it, but I thought it would be smart to get someone else's input on this.

Answer (score 56):

You can pass any object into the object argument of the RunWorkerAsync call, and then retrieve the arguments from within the DoWork event. You can also pass arguments from the DoWork event to the RunWorkerCompleted event using the Result variable in the DoWorkEventArgs.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

        object paramObj = 1;
        object paramObj2 = 2;

        // The parameters you want to pass to the do work event of the background worker.
        object[] parameters = new object [] { paramObj, paramObj2 };

        // This runs the event on new background worker thread.
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] parameters = e.Argument as object[];

        // do something.

        e.Result = true;
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        object result = e.Result;

        // Handle what to do when complete.                        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! Is there any way to pass references with `DoWorkEventArgs`?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way that comes to my mind would be creating a class with a property for every object you have, and passing that.

```
public class MyWorkerContext
{
   public Object1 Worker;
   public Object2 Parameter1;
   public Object2 Parameter2;
}
```

then in the DoWork you simply do something like:

```
MyWorkerContext context = e.Argument as MyWorkerContext;

context.Worker.Method(context.Parameter1, context.Parameter2);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can capture them in a lambda for DoWork:

```
bgw.DoWork += (sender, e) => object.Method(paramObj, paramObj2) ;
```

`e.Argument` (i.e. the state value or object passed to `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()`) could be 1 of the 3, but it is of type `System.Object` and would require boxing. Passing all of the parameters directly in the lambda gives you full type-safety on all of the parameters without any need for boxing or casting.

Comment: Ok, so what does this look like in the DoWork method?

Comment: Chris, the part after the `+=` _is_ the DoWork method.

Comment: I noticed. What gets passed to RunWorkerAsync here?

Comment: The state param, you can leave it out:  `() => ...`

Comment: _"I like Brizio's answer better"_ -- I don't know which answer you're referring to (I assume one of the other answerers changed their user name at some point), but IMHO your answer is the preferable approach. It implicitly creates the parameter-holding class described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794446), providing type-safe access to the parameters without boxing, and without the actual hassle of writing the parameter-holding type.

Comment: Though, on re-reading your answer, I realized it doesn't actually work. The event handler for `DoWork` has to match the signature of the event. I've edited your answer so that less-experienced C# programmers will more easily be able to apply your advice.

Comment: Yes, OK about the edit. My objection here is that paramObj1 and paramObj2 are captured, and that fact is not so obvious.

Comment: It's a valid objection, to some limited extent. IMHO, if one is not comfortable with the compiler doing things with the code that are "not so obvious", C# is probably the wrong language to is. It's one of the more "syntactical sugar"-heavy languages I've used (though, many other are following its lead, and the lead of similar languages). More to the point, _performance_-wise, your proposal is not much different from allocating an array and storing things in it (except that requires boxing of each value) or explicitly writing a class and storing things in it. This way is just easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an Object into the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() method.  You should wrap your two paramObjs into one Object (you could use an array, a tuple, or some other composite class that you would write) and pass that as the argument into RunWorkerAsync().

Then, when your DoWork event is raised, you can retrieve this values by looking at the Argument property of the DoWorkEventArgs parameter of the event handler.

For a complete example, check out on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.90%29.aspx