# Forms, controls and threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, controls

So I moved a method into the DoWork event of a background worker so as to not kill the UI while accessing remote resources. I was fully aware as I was doing this that a bit of refactoring would be in order because the method accesses some controls on the form - not a thread friendly thing to do. To my amazement, no, it ran just fine. Odd but I didn't question it, though it still rattled around in my head. Strange.

Then I added another control, a ComboBox for timezone selection. I added the line to the DoWork method to access the value and BAM...Cross thread operation not valid.

```
 private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, new Status("Initializing...", StatusState.Initializing));

     Query query = new Query();
     query.Hostname = textBoxHostname.Text;                         // Valid...
     query.Port = Int32.Parse(textBoxPort.Text);                    // Valid...
     query.Point = Int32.Parse(textBoxPoint.Text);                  // Valid...
     query.Start = dateTimePickerStart.Value;                       // Valid...
     query.End = dateTimePickerEnd.Value;                           // Valid...
     query.Sampling = Sampling.Parse(textBoxSampling.Text);         // Valid...
     query.Timezone = (TimeZoneInfo)comboBoxTimezone.SelectedValue; // Not Valid!

     // Run query
}
```

So why is it that all the other calls to controls created on the other thread are just fine, but this one blows up? My guess is some sort of caching on the .NET side of things so that the underlying control is never actually accessed for the others. May have to dig into some Reference Source soon if there are no replies.

I suppose I should I add that I have fixed the error by simply building the Query object and passing it to the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` call. I'm really looking for an explanation rather than a solution.

Comment: You should be passing all of those values as parameters when running the BackgroundWorker.  See [Basic BackgroundWorker usage with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5794386/719186).

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, I knew that going in and that's how I have fixed it. I'm trying to understand why the rest don't have the same problem. I expected to have this problem on the first access to `textBoxHostname.Text`.

Comment: I didn't see anything in your post claiming you fixed it, hence, the suggested comment I made.  Does the ComboBox have a DataSource?

Comment: No datasource, just items (`TimeZoneInfo` obejcts) added in `Load()`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm really looking for and explanation

Microsoft is simply inconsistent in this respect.  You know you shouldn't be accessing the TextBox from a different thread, but did anyway.  Some controls will allow you to **Read** their values from another thread, while others won't.  Regardless, you **shouldn't** do it in the first place.  ;)

As an alternative to passing in everything to `RunWorkerAsync()`, you could do:

```
 Query query = new Query();
 this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
     query.Hostname = textBoxHostname.Text;                         // Valid...
     query.Port = Int32.Parse(textBoxPort.Text);                    // Valid...
     query.Point = Int32.Parse(textBoxPoint.Text);                  // Valid...
     query.Start = dateTimePickerStart.Value;                       // Valid...
     query.End = dateTimePickerEnd.Value;                           // Valid...
     query.Sampling = Sampling.Parse(textBoxSampling.Text);         // Valid...
     query.Timezone = (TimeZoneInfo)comboBoxTimezone.SelectedValue; // Not Valid!
 });
```