# Which button was clicked using background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have several buttons that do some things using background worker. I would like to know which button was clicked, so I did this:

```
public MyClass()
{
    _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    _worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void First_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Second_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    switch (clickedButton.Name)
    {
        case "First_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(true);
            break;
        case "Second_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(false);
            break;
        case null:
            return;
    }
}
```

When I click one of the buttons, I get `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' .`

I know the importance of thread-safe calls and I've done this before with the help of [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I've no idea how to handle this problem. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand. When you click on a button, you know automatically which was clicked with the OnClick event... Can you show us more code ?

Comment: How are you invoking button clicks?

Comment: What event are you running this code from? Obviously not the button click event

Comment: @RonanLamour: You can attach the same handler to different control events. So you can have multiple buttons with the same handle, using `sender` allows you to identify the object that raised the event

Comment: You need to read carefully this one [Basic BackgroundWorker usage with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794386/basic-backgroundworker-usage-with-parameters)

Comment: I edited my post, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is the object that raised the event, so in your case it will be a `BackgroundWorker` object, and not a `Button`. This is why that cast fails.

You can pass the button name to the background worker by using the overload that accepts an object. This can then be used inside the `DoWork` event.

For example:

```
private void First_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync("First_Button");
}

private void Second_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync("Second_Button");
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string buttonName = (string)e.Argument;

    switch (buttonName)
    {
        case "First_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(true);
            break;
        case "Second_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(false);
            break;
        case null:
            return;
    }
}
```

Just for thought, I always find it's a good idea to create a dedicate class for background worker argument, that way you can easily pass multiple values if needed.

Comment: Yeah, this is how it looks like and your solution works. Thanks :) Do you know any sources where I can look up some more info about background workers or threading in general?

Answer (score 0):

Does this is more close of what you want to perform ?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Second_Button.Click += ButtonClick;
    First_Button.Click += ButtonClick;
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var directory = String.Empty;
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    switch (clickedButton.Name)
    {
        case "First_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(true);
            break;
        case "Second_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(false);
            break;
        case null:
            return;
    }

    First_Button.Enabled = false;
    Second_Button.Enabled = false;
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (o, args) =>
    {
        // your work. You can use directory here
    };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
    {
        First_Button.Enabled = true;
        Second_Button.Enabled = true;
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

}
```

or maybe even better :

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var directory = String.Empty;
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    switch (clickedButton.Name)
    {
        case "First_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(true);
            break;
        case "Second_Button":
            directory = _ftp.GetCurrentDate(false);
            break;
        case null:
            return;
    }

    First_Button.Enabled = false;
    Second_Button.Enabled = false;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // your work. you can use directory here



    });

    First_Button.Enabled = true;
    Second_Button.Enabled = true;

}
```

Comment: No, I've edited my post so you can see how I handle this. But thanks for your effort anyway :)

Comment: Np :) Please also look at my async/await solution because theses are new way of performing background tasks very easily, introduced in .net 4.5.